# How can you take the first 2 or 3 numbers from a serial number and find the year they were manufactured?

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I have a list of 2000 serial numbers and I am trying to gather information from them. All of the serial numbers start with the year they were manufactured and a number that correlates to the month (i.e. 00J49938... refers to a machine manufactured in October (J is the 10h letter in the alphabet) of 2000 (00).

At the moment, I created a list comprehension that looks like:
`year_2001 = [i for i in df['serial_number'] if i.startswith('01')]`

I can do this for every month and year respectively, but is there a way that I could create a function that takes a year as an input and cuts out creating a list comprehension for every month of every year?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Make it easy to assist you: [mcve]

Comment: Convert the first two digits to a number, and add that to `2000` to get the year. Use `ord()` to convert the third character to a number, and subtract the code for `A` from that.

Comment: I'm not clear on the desired result.  Do you need only the year (in which case your description of month codes is needless), the year and month, or lists of serial numbers for each year?

Comment: Where are you stuck?  You seem to have simple steps, each of which is covered quite well in examples and tutorials.  You should have a coding attempt to post.

Answer (score 3):

You can use logic similar to this:

```
select 2000 + cast(left(serial_number, 2) as int) as year,
       substr(serial_number, 3, 1) - ascii('A') + 1 as month
```

The exact functions might differ a bit, depending on the database.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to do this in pandas. You can attempt something like this

```
import pandas as pd

# Create dictionary mapping for months
month_mapping = {'A': 'January',
                'B': 'February',
                'C': 'March',
                'D': 'April',
                'E': 'May',
                'F': 'June',
                'G': 'July',
                'H': 'August',
                'I': 'September',
                'J': 'October',
                'K': 'November',
                'L': 'December'}


# Create sample dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(['00J49938','00G49939', '01L49940'], columns=['sn'])

# Create extra columns matching specific criteria
df['Year'] = df['sn'].apply(lambda s:2000 if s[:2]=='00' else 2001)

# This uses the above month_mapping. You can use a similar dictionary method for the year as well
df['Month'] = df['sn'].apply(lambda s:month_mapping.get(s[2],None))
df['Product Code'] = df['sn'].str[3:]
df
```